# chrome browser is being launched eventhough firefox is configured as the browser in testng.xml

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid2

Trying to run parallel tests in chrome and firefox. During the execution another chrome browser is being launched instead of the firefox browser and it is being ignored. below are the versions of files being used
**OS - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS,
Firefox version - 54,
gecko version - v0.18,
Chrome version -60.0.311,
Chrome Driver - 2.53**

***testng.xml***

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="AutomationSuite" parallel="tests">
    <test name="TestCaratLaneInFireFox">
        <parameter name="node" value="http://*******:4444/wd/hub"/>
        <parameter name="browser" value="Firefox"/>
        <packages>
            <package name="script"/>
        </packages>
    </test>
    <test name="TestCaratLaneInChrome">
        <parameter name="node" value="http://****:4444/wd/hub"/>
        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
        <packages>
            <package name="script"/>
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

***BaseTest.Java***

```java
public class BaseTest implements IAutoConst {

    public WebDriver driver;

    static {    
        System.setProperty(CHROME_KEY, CHROME_VALUE);
        System.setProperty(GECKO_KEY, GECKO_VALUE);
    }

    @Parameters({"node","browser"})
    @BeforeMethod
    public void openApplication(String node,String browser) throws MalformedURLException {

        // ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        // options.addArguments("--disable-notifications"); 
        URL system = new URL(node);
        DesiredCapabilities whichBrowser = new DesiredCapabilities();
        whichBrowser.setBrowserName(browser);
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(system,whichBrowser);
        driver.get(URL);        
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(ITO, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        //driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void closeApplication() {
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

***Emailable Report:*** [image: Report]

Comment: Which test are you running?

Comment: trying to run both tests parallel. running the scripts on package level.

Comment: Are the tests run on remote machines? or on the same machine?

Comment: Tests run on the same machine.

Comment: I do not think parallel tests possible on the same machine for browser testing.

Comment: have tried this in windows machine before and it was working as expected. not sure why it is not opening in ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gecko driver version which was kept in hub had a different version than in the node. Hence it stopped the Firefox from launching.

Comment: I am not sure if you were adding a comment or if you were trying to answer your own question. If you were just adding a comment, please delete off this answer. If you were trying to answer your own question, I would suggest that you please elaborate your answer such that others who may end up landing on your question get enough context so that they are also benefitted by the answer.